# Stack overflow results

Tags: microcontroller, flash, stack

I have been forcing a problem regarding to corruption of the MCU flash memory content during software running. This corruption occurs randomly and I have got an idea whether the flash memory corruption could be result of stack overflow event. Is it ever possible? After all stack is in the RAM. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Also don't forget to check VCC. Brownouts can potentially damage the flash, too. Be sure that the brownout reset is enabled, especially during fash programming.

Comment: Do you have some manner of bootloader/flash programming as part of the firmware? Is this new products or products that have been in the field for a long time?

Comment: @Lundin Yes there is a bootloader at the beginning of the flash memory of the MCU which is part of newly developed product. Several flash sectors dedicated just for the bootloader has been corrupted namely erased.

Comment: Then yeah it is somewhat likely. Upon getting a stack overflow inside a function, the return address often turns to garbage. If whatever's on the stack at that point happens to be an address to code inside the bootloader, bad things will happen. Similarly, if you have an amateur memory layout where the stack grows into .data/.bss or MCU registers, literally anything can happen. Therefore it's always good practice to let the stack grow (downwards in this case) into non-volatile memory or addresses that causes a trap/hardware exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, yes. If your processor support self-programming instructions, and you execute arbitrary memory as instructions due to stack overflow, anything the processor can do is *possible*. Usually self programming requires some conditions to be met,  but specifics depend on the processor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reaction vicatcu. I have been using the STM32F417 MCU. Do you have any experience with diagnostics of this issue?

Comment: Although possible, this seems quite unlikely. Unless the runaway code jumps into some flash bootloader, then it is quite likely. Many Cortex M have some manner of bootloader pre-programmed in flash. Not sure if that's the case here.